# Is there any ReactJS library for drawing sine wave from audio analyser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, visualization, web-audio-api

In web app, I should implement drawing sine wave to visualize while recording from the mic. I am using Web Audio API to get data from the mic.

```
 const { audioData } = this.props;
    const canvas = this.canvas.current;
    const height = canvas.height;
    const width = canvas.width;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let x = 0;
    const sliceWidth = (width * 1.0) / audioData.length;

    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, height / 4);
    for (const item of audioData) {
      const y = (item / 255.0) * height;
      context.lineTo(x, y);
      x += sliceWidth;
    }
    context.lineTo(x, height / 2);
    context.stroke();
```

[image]

Comment: The HTML5 canvas is a good application for this. Does it need to be a React library? :)

Comment: Yeah it is but I couldn't create such a sine canvas animation